# Practical Kabbalah saving lives

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah

In a situation of pikuach nefesh (for one Jew or many Jews or even for a non Jew or many non Jews), if one knows how to utilize Kabbalah Masseios (Practical Kabbalah - Using Divine names for "powers") - can he? To save the person(s) from death? Or is that changing GDs plan (why is that different than praying)?

Comment: Isn't this the explicit case of the gemara if לוחשים על המכה? Some rishonim thought it is permitted because it has magical powers and actually helps and some rishonim thought it was permitted because it helps calm the sick person even though it's completely ineffective.

Comment: How is this question different from "Can I go to a doctor and take medicine or is that changing God's plan?"

Answer (score 3):

There are countless stories of Sages in every age doing such things including in the current day. It is not the common practice and is prohibited for almost everyone to indulge in such activity for a variety of reasons.

One textual example that comes to mind of this type of teaching is [Sefer Ta'alumot Chochmah by Rabbi Chaim Vital](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=11565.gif) which actually categorizes according those methods tried and tested and those only heard of, as well as their efficacy.

There is also the famous amulet of [Rabbi Mordechai Sharabi, zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Sharabi) which was used by Rav Kaduri, zt"l and Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu, zt"l. This link actually connects to a photo of [one of the notebooks from Rav Kaduri, zt"l about writing amulets](https://www.virtualjudaica.com/Listing/Details/1249369/Amulets-by-R-Yitzhak-Kaduri-Kadouri-Jerusalem-20th-century) that was placed up for auction in 2018.

Comment: if it's prohibited to do (now) then whence did the Rabbis learn to do such (magical/Kabbalistic) practices?

Comment: @Moshe I didn’t say it is prohibited now. I said currently, it is prohibited for almost everyone. I also emphasized that there are a variety of reasons. But it should be noted which reason or reasons apply to each individual are different.

Comment: I think the word prohibited is too strong. More like very dangerous.

Comment: @N.T. According to Rav Kaduri zt”l, it is prohibited for most. That is the language he uses. If you would like independent confirmation, contact Rav Ariel Bar Tzadok. It causes great damage both spiritually and physically.